# Javascript: Access a class instance from a different context

Tags: javascript

I have a class which has already been initialized (via the new keyword). Now I'm within a different context and I need access to the same instance of this class in order to access its method. I don't want to have to create a new instance of the class.

For example, I have 2 Views in an overlay (View1 and View2). View1 is invoked via a button click and within View1 is a button to access View2. When that button in View1 is clicked, I want View1 to be destroyed such that the only overlay left on screen is View2.

### View1 Controller

```
function View1Controller() {
  this.view1 = new View1();
}
```

### Class View1

```
function View1() {

}
View1.prototype.close = function() {

};
```

### Class View2

```
function View2() {

}
View2.prototype.open = function() {

  // close View1
  // I need access to the initialized view1 in View1Controller so I can call View1 close()
};
```

### Class Controller for View2

```
function Controller() {

  this.view2 = new View2();
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, get it in the scope. Without seeing at least how your code is structured, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: Take a reference of your instantiated object to the new context, and *voilá*, you have access to that instance's methods.

Comment: @drecute Can you explain why you want to access `View1` methods from within `View2`? The two classes should not be interdependent, from an architectural point of view. If you want to call `.close()` on a `View1` instance, you must pass that instance as an argument to `.open()`.

Comment: I agree with Tomalak. You should inject the other view from the controller, View2 may not have a hardcoded reference to another view. That's the point of MVC.

Comment: @Tomalak That sounds like a hack to me. But you are right that they should not be interdependent. What I'm thinking of doing is to take this to the controller such that if I need to close a view, I should fire an event that the controller should handle in order to invoke the corresponding method of the View.

Comment: That would be another possibility. Your code sample is not really sufficient to understand the exact situation you want to solve, so it's hard to see the ideal solution. Maybe it helps if you add one or two paragraphs of description?

Comment: @Tomalak Please see edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: I see. According to your description view1 initiates view2, so it would be logical that you pass view1 to view2 as the "initiator/sender/parent". Which view2 can then close, if desired. Maybe it's not entirely clean but it's not too dirty either. The other obvious variant would be to invoke view2 from the button within view1 and have view1 close itself after that.

Comment: @Tomalak View1 doesn't know anything about View2, neither does View2. View1 doesn't directly invoke View2. I just know that once the action on View1 has finished executing, View2 should be displayed.

Comment: While implementing this, I realize that even if I have to take this through the controller I will need access to a single instance of any of the Views. Hence, going with Singleton.

Comment: Using a singleton solely as a substitute for a global (or outer-scope) variable is not very clean either. Sounds like overkill to me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats what Singleton design pattern is intended for if you need only one instance of that class at all.

Comment: Singleton is flawed in my context. Imagine if `init` of `mySingleton` class takes arguments, how do I access those parameters in getinstance()?

Comment: Load them into the singleton instance? @drecute

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Javascript does not have classes.  Javascript has objects.  It's an important distinction you'll learn about as you learn the language better.

Second, objects are always passed by reference, not by value.

That means that when you "copy" an object, as with using the `=` operator, you're simply making another variable refer to the same object.

Therefore, you want to set a variable equal to the object where the variable is accessible from both scopes (in the worst case, a global variable).  It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do from the question, so if this doesn't help, may I suggest that you post an example of what you want to do?

The solution probably looks like this:

```
var g_dog;

f1();
f2();

function f1() {
    var dog = new Dog();
    g_dog = dog;
}

function f2() {
    g_dog.bark();
}
```